# This mysql_connect Attribute seems to old how can I replace them?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I cannot connect to my Data Base using this way:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("1");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("2");
```

After the connection to the data base I would like to create a `while` loop with the elements of the data base, this is my code:

```
$carlistreq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand="'.$_GET['marq'].'"") or die("3");
$count = mysql_num_rows($carlistreq);

if($count==0)
{
   echo "No elements";
}
else
{
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        //my code
    }
}
```

The issue comes from my SQL attributes like:

```
mysql_connect
mysql_fetch_array
mysql_select_db
```

For example.

Here is the error:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:[....]
>   on line 2

Comment: [Your question was already been answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) Please, read the question and answer of this link carefully. You'll gonna find every answer you're looking for.

Comment: Here is the [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class manual, and here's the [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) one. Both replace your needs. They are quite simple to use, and `mysqli_` states for "MySQL Improved", which is why you're gonna find much similarity between them. If you find any trouble implementing it, please open a question concerning your issue so we can help you properly. :)

Comment: Thank you @Tanuel Mategi solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the mysqli-extension like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database") or die("1");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand='".$_GET['marq']."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        //do something with your $row here
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName', 'User' , 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes now servers are going to handel mysqli and PDO. Try implementing this code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?> 

// Change database to "test"
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

// ...some PHP code for database "test"...

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You can user http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php as reference to understand better how mysqli works.